# MSVC environment variables not showing up in different terminals

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64, haxe, hxcpp

I'm using Haxe's HXCPP to generate C++ code and compile it with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition. I'm following [this](http://gamehaxe.com/2011/04/05/nme-from-scratch/) guide and it asks you to run `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"` so that `cl.exe` (the compiler) is in your build path.

This *does* allow me to run cl.exe, but only in that terminal. It fails if I attempt to run it from another terminal or within my IDE (Sublime Text 2).

I figured out a workaround: manually copy+paste variable values from the terminal to the GUI environment variable editor.

There's gotta be a better way. What am I missing?

build.hxml

```
-main Test
-cpp bin
```

Test.hx

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        trace("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Error message when building

```
link.exe -out:Test.exe -nologo -machine:x86 -libpath:lib user32.lib -libpath:e:/VS8/PlatformSDK/Lib @all_objs
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'user32.lib'
Called from ? line 1
Called from BuildTool.hx line 1246
Called from BuildTool.hx line 554
Called from BuildTool.hx line 591
Called from BuildTool.hx line 710
Called from BuildTool.hx line 796
Called from BuildTool.hx line 285
```

Answer (score 1):

You must run the following command for each terminal (environment) that you have open:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat
```

The environment variables that it defines are all local.

Comment: The issue with this is that the thing that fails is the haxe compiler, so I would need to modify that in order for it to run correctly. (I ended up just manually copying the environment variables.)